# Generic type reflection in TypeScript

Tags: reflection, typescript

Can I determine the generic type `T` in the following scenario?

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
    }

    GenericMethod<T>(): string {
        return typeof(T);           // <=== this is flagged by the compiler,
                                    //      and returns undefined at runtime
    }
}

class MyClass2 {
}

alert(new MyClass().GenericMethod<MyClass2>());
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the types are erased during compilation, they are not available when the code runs.

This means you have to make a small duplication...

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
    }

    GenericMethod<T>(targetType: any): string {
        return typeof(targetType); 
    }
}

class MyClass2 {
}

alert(new MyClass().GenericMethod<MyClass2>(MyClass2));
```

In this case, you end up with the answer `function`, but you probably wanted `MyClass2`.

I have written an [example of how to get runtime type names in TypeScript](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201304/Blog/Obtaining-A-Class-Name-At-Runtime-In-TypeScript/), which looks like this:

```
class Describer {
    static getName(inputClass) { 
        var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
        var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((<any> inputClass).constructor.toString());
        return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
    }
}

class Example {
}

class AnotherClass extends Example {
}

var x = new Example();
alert(Describer.getName(x)); // Example

var y = new AnotherClass();
alert(Describer.getName(y)); // AnotherClass
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.