# Determining/accessing the type of a generic parameter?

Tags: typescript

I need to refactor a function that hydrates values from localStorage:

```
export function hydrateFromLocalStorage<T>(key: string): T {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))
  }
  catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

If the type `T` is anything other than an object, it doesn't need to be passed through the JSON parser.

I have seen many examples of using [ReturnType](https://dev.to/busypeoples/notes-on-typescript-returntype-3m5a), but not within the function body. Is it possible to determine `T` within the function?

Comment: *"If the type T is anything other than an object, it doesn't need to be passed through the JSON parser."* Why not? What if `T` is `number`, for instance? (Since web storage only stores strings.) I'd consistently use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` (probably with a replacer/reviver to handle dates, in my case...)

Comment: Note that [`localStorage.getItem(key)` *always* returns a string (or null)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), no matter what you put in there.

Comment: I'm not sure why I would need to pass a simple string or simple number through the JSON parser?

Comment: @Brandon - You could store the string directly. You can't store the number directly, it'll get converted to string. The advantage to consistently using `JSON.stringify` when storing and `JSON.parse` when retrieving is you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: From the TypeScript side of things, no, there's no way to do different things at runtime based on results of the type system.  The type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) at runtime, so the JS will look like `function hydrate(key) { ... }` with no `T` at all.  It's usually more fruitful to imagine writing in pure JavaScript and then add typings to it, not the other way around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic type reflection in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990107/generic-type-reflection-in-typescript)

Comment: Gotcha. Let me take a look at the reflection answer and see what I can do. Thank you all very much for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking the problem, as usual.

If you simply use `JSON.stringify()` to set the value before attempting to re-hydrate the value, it's not necessary to know the return type of the generic parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just perform regular type check?

```
export function hydrateFromLocalStorage<T>(key: string): T {
  try {
    const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (typeof value === object) {
      return JSON.parse(value);
    }
    return value;
  }
  catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `if` condition will never be true (unless you have a variable called `object` with the value `"string"` in it -- but I'm guessing you meant `"object"`, not `object`). `localStorage` **only** stores strings, so `typeof value` will always be `"string"`.